# Disable search and filter on specific column on MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, material-table, disable

Is there a way to disable searching and filtering only for specific column on MaterialTable? I enabled these functionalities automatically:

```
<MaterialTable
    filtering: true,
    search: false,
<MaterialTable?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as written in the docs, you can set `filtering` false for each column which you want to disable.
This will result in something like this:
[image]
If you want to keep the seach in the header, but you want to only filter for only one column, you can override `customFilterAndSearch` for each column and return true, for all columns, where you want to disable the searching.
Check out these links: [Search](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/search) and [Filtering](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering).

Comment: Great, can you accept my answer then do other can find it?